# Is there any reason for count() method in Sugar ORM to take String[] parameter instead of String...?

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

I'm developing a simple quiz solving app and in the database there's many-to-one relation between the questions and the quizzes, so that a single quiz can have multiple questions assigned to it.

To get every question of a quiz I'm simply calling:

```
Question.find(Question.class, "quiz = ?", String.valueOf(quiz.getId()));
```

Sometimes though, I would like to know how many questions there are, I thought I can just do:

```
Question.count(Question.class, "quiz = ?", String.valueOf(quiz.getId()));
```

Unfortunately, unlike `find()`, `SugarRecord.count()` method accepts array of `String`s, so I have to call it like:

```
Question.count(Question.class, "quiz = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(quiz.getId())});
```

Is there any reason for that kind of inconsistency in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being the usage of overloading. There is a method with `groupBy, orderBy` and `limit`. Dumb, dumb, dumb.

```
public static <T> long count(Class<T> type); 
public static <T> long count(Class<T> type, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);
public static <T> long count(Class<T> type, String whereClause,
        String[] whereArgs, String groupBy, String orderBy, String limit);
```

However make your own:

```
public static <T> long countWhere(Class<T> type, String whereClause, String... whereArgs) {
     return Question.count(type, whereClause, whereArgs);
}
```

Comment: Ugh, I didn't notice that, thank you. It makes me sad how ugly that is.